# JWT authentication with AXIOS

Tags: authentication, vue.js, jwt, axios

Using Vue webpack template, trying to make JWT authentication. What I've done so far:

"src/auth/index.js":

```
  // Send a request to the login URL and save the returned JWT
  login (creds, redirect) {
    axios.post(LOGIN_URL, creds, (data) => {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token)

      this.user.authenticated = true

      // Redirect to a specified route
      if (redirect) {
        router.push(redirect)
      }
    }).error((err) => {
      context.error = err
    })
  },
```

I'm calling this function from LoginPage.vue:

```
  methods: {
    login () {
      var credentials = {
        username: this.credentials.username,
        password: this.credentials.password
      }
      // We need to pass the component's this context
      // to properly make use of http in the auth service
      auth.login(this, credentials, 'requests')
    }
  }
```

When I'm submitting the form, data is submitted, but I get the following error in a console:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_axios___default.a.post(...).error is not a function
```

Also JWT token is not saving in my local storage, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are u using error after post ? Where did u find this ?

Comment: Try .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrote login function:

```
  login (context, creds, redirect) {
    axios.post(LOGIN_URL, creds)
      .then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access_token)

        this.user.authenticated = true

        if (redirect) {
          router.push(redirect)
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        context.error = err.response.data
      })
  },
```

Everything is working now.